# MaskedTextBox text length properties return same value

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I have MaskedTextBox with following mask

```
MaskedTextBox.Mask = @"000\.000\.000\.000";
```

For test I create textBox where I show length of the text written in MaskedTextBox. First I add EventHandler:

```
MaskedTextBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(MaskedTextBoxTextChanged);
```

and write test function to handle behaviour of MaskedTextBox:

```
private void MaskedTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MaskedTextBox mtb = sender as MaskedTextBox;
   TextBox.Text = mtb.Text.Length.ToString();
}
```

Result is not good at all, because when I type first character in MaskedTextBox from the left the lenght properties should be 1. It's not 1, it's 12, and this number is rise after 12 postion. How to repair this bug? Moreover, I try to fill this MaskedTextBox with zeros character after call MaskedTextBoxTextChanged method and I want to use Text.Length properties.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the length of your **string** will be 15, not 12 (being a string, the separators are counted).

As for the length, a quick test shows me that the minimum length will be the length of the string up to the last separator.

However, the length is not really relevant as your mask implies that all elements are digit, and none are optional.  Therefore it is NOT a valid input if values are not supplied for all element.

If you are masking input to receive a number, you might need to convert that to a numeric data type first in order to do whatever processing you are doing (which we don't know).

Comment: I try to process IPAddress. When I type on input "127" I have "127. . . " output than System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse return false, because it's not a valid IPAddress. When I type "127" (output "127. . . ") than fill space with zeros than I get right IP value.

Comment: That's what the `TypeValidationCompleted` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.typevalidationcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `MaskInputRejected` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.maskinputrejected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events are for.